# How to remove gap between rows in MS Access Report

Tags: ms-access, gridlines, ms-access-reports

I have created an MS Access database.

I've used a black border colour for the rows/records. In Report View, the report looks exactly as how I designed it in Design View and Layout View, but when I use Print Preview, there is a noticeable gap between rows/records.

I made sure to set the `Autoheight = No`, `Can Shrink = No`, `Can Grow = No` and the detail height is the same as the highest field.

[image]

I tried overlaying a horizontal line on the bottom border of the Design View.

Voila - the gap is gone, but replaced by a thick horizontal line, and only on a few rows. The gap is only gone on the bottom of the 1<sup>st</sup>, 5<sup>th</sup> and 9<sup>th</sup> line, which is quite peculiar. The rest of the rows have gaps.

I also tried setting the bottom Gridline to black but the result is the same as above.

[image]

I changed the colour of the horizontal to see where the horizontal line has gone:

[image]

It turns out that on some rows, the horizontal line is perfectly overlayed on the bottom border, and on some rows, the horizontal line is situated below the rows, making the gap/white space gone.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why - my guess is rounding inaccuracies with floating point numbers (heights). If you use US localization, you could try setting a "straight" number like 0.2 inch as height for controls and detail section. -- I always suspected that us metric system users are more affected by these issues, e.g. Access auto-changing values like 0.5 cm to 0.501 cm.

Comment: I would suggest applying the gridline to just the top *or* bottom of each record, such that the preceding or succeeding record shares the gridline with the record above or below.

Comment: @Andre might have identified cause. I am in U.S. and don't have this issue. Detail section and textbox both set to 0.2917 inch height.

Comment: I have the same problem. I removed borders and drew vertical and horizontal lines instead. My solution takes a lot of time and it takes a lot of effort when you want to edit the report. That's why I did not post it as an answer.